# Selenium Webdriver - Slider NOT working as per the value from excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I would like to move Slider in a page based on the value from excel (Apache POI)

In the Excel I have value for answer_weight as "98"

Here is the code that I used. When I run the code Slider is set at "53" but I want to set the slider at 98. Could you please help

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.click(answerweight).build().perform();
    for (int i = 100; i >= answer_weight; i--) 
    {
        action.sendKeys(Keys.RIGHT).build().perform();
     }
```

Comment: are you sure that  for each time you press the right key then the the slider will decrease the count by 1?

Comment: No Sudharsan it doesn't decrease by 1

Comment: can you share relevant HTML code for the slider or url for the application?

Comment: Put a slight pause (50ms?) after your `.sendKeys()` and see if that helps. It may just be clicking too fast.